# node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

I keep getting this error when running 'npm run dev' and not sure why...

Node version: 14.16.0 (it's an older app)

Error:

> node: --openssl-legacy-provider is not allowed in NODE_OPTIONS

package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && cross-env NODE_ENV=development nuxt-ts",
    "build": "export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider && cross-env NODE_ENV=production nuxt-ts build",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
  },
```

Comment: Took me 37s to find a solution on Google. Did you make that effort initially?

Comment: @kissu yea, actually I did... took me to stackoverflow with the top 10 threads.. tried every single one of them and it still failed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe it is because your node version doesn't support it, try just this -

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nuxt-ts",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nuxt-ts build",
    "postinstall": "patch-package"
}
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to help me by providing a proper solution. much appreciated.